# Migrating Groovy gradle to Kotlin gradle (ext missing, or closure conversion, not sure)

Tags: gradle, groovy, kotlin

I have some Git helper written in groovy:

git.gradle:

```
def gitHash() {
    def res = 'git rev-parse --short HEAD'.execute([], project.rootDir).text.trim()

    def diff = 'git diff'.execute([], project.rootDir).text.trim()
    if (diff != null && diff.length() > 0) {
        res += "-dirty"
    }

    return res
}

// method needs to be converted to closure, in order to be visible outside of script
ext.gitHash =  { return gitHash();}
```

Now I converted whole stuff to Kotlin, looks like this now:

git.gradle.kts:

```
import java.io.IOException
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

fun gitHash() : String {
    var res = "git rev-parse --short HEAD".runCommand(project.rootDir)?.trim()

    val diff = "git diff".runCommand(project.rootDir)?.trim()
    if (diff != null && diff.isNotEmpty()) {
        res += "-dirty"
    }
    return res!!
}

fun String.runCommand(workingDir: File): String? {
    ...
}

// method needs to be converted to closure, in order to be visible outside of script
//ext.gitHash =  { return gitHash();} // <-- HERE'S THE PROBLEM

task("gitTask") { // <-- calling ./gradlew gitTask works
    println(gitHash())
}
```

Main script includes these like this:

```
//apply from: 'git.gradle'
apply from: 'git.gradle.kts'

println gitHash() // works with Groovy, doesn't with Kotlin
```

Now, problem is, that main script can't recognize gitHash() method, most likely because I can't expose it via ext closure. Same as in Groovy script, this method seems to be private (or local) in that file.

As far I understand, ext closure is shorthand of 'project.extra' which I was trying to integrate. Also, it seems that typical Groovy closure have no equivalent in Kotlin. I stuck here, without any idea what else could I try. Any ideas welcome.

**UPDATE**

With:

```
var gitHash: Closure<Any?> by extra
gitHash = closureOf<String> { }
gitHash.delegate = { gitHash() }
```

I'm able to work with it in Groovy like:

```
println gitHash.invoke()
```

But it doesn't work with Kotlin script... because invoke() points to call() (https://github.com/gradle/gradle-script-kotlin/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/org/gradle/script/lang/kotlin/GroovyInteroperability.kt extension methods here). And while I'm trying to use it as closure `gitHash()` it leads to such error:

```
Parameter specified as non-null is null: method org.gradle.script.lang.kotlin.KotlinClosure.doCall, parameter it
```

It looks like I'm missing something...

Comment: I'm not skilful enough in kotlin but maybe this example will help you somehow: https://github.com/gradle/gradle-script-kotlin/blob/master/samples/extra-properties/build.gradle.kts

Comment: @Opal Unfortunatelly no, the closest one I found is https://github.com/gradle/gradle-script-kotlin/tree/master/samples/groovy-interop , but I'd like to do exactly opposite . This one sets extras on Groovy side, while reading it on Kotlin side. I'm trying to set on Kotlin side, and read on Groovy side.

Comment: Ok, looks like setting values is done like this: 
    `var gitHash: String by extra`
    `gitHash = "works"`

Question is still, how to deal with closures...

Comment: Yes, that's right, however how to set the values that is a reference to a function?

Comment: I see there are few helpers https://github.com/gradle/gradle-script-kotlin/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/org/gradle/script/lang/kotlin/GroovyInteroperability.kt but, right now `var gitHash: Closure<Any?> by extra;
gitHash = closureOf<Any>({ gitHash() });` should do the job according to this. However it doesn't, but `var gitHash: Closure<Any?> by extra;
gitHash = closureOf<String> { };
gitHash.delegate = { gitHash() };` and in groovy `println gitHash.invoke()` works like a charm. Better than nothing, but i can't believe that it's best way to do so :)

Comment: First one throws such error... Parameter specified as non-null is null: method org.gradle.script.lang.kotlin.KotlinClosure.doCall, parameter it

Answer (score 0):

In case you're still looking for a solution, here's what I'd suggest:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream

inline
fun String.runCommand(workingDir: File): String {
    val command = this
    val stdout = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    project.exec {
        this.workingDir = workingDir
        this.commandLine = command.split(" ")
        this.standardOutput = stdout
    }
    return String(stdout.toByteArray()).trim()
}

task("gitHash") {
    var res = "git rev-parse --short HEAD".runCommand(project.rootDir)
    val diff = "git diff".runCommand(project.rootDir)
    if (!diff.isNullOrBlank()) { res += "-dirty" }
    println(res)
}
```

I've tested it with [Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/userguide.html) [4.6+](https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/release-notes.html)

.. or perhaps the more idiomatic:

```
inline
fun String.runCommand(workingDir: File): String {
    val stdout = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    project.exec {
        this.workingDir = workingDir
        this.commandLine = this@runCommand.split(" ")
        this.standardOutput = stdout
    }
    return String(stdout.toByteArray()).trim()
}

val commitHash by lazy { "git rev-parse --short HEAD".runCommand(project.rootDir) }
val workingCopyDiff by lazy { "git diff".runCommand(project.rootDir) }

val gitHash by tasks.creating {
    println(commitHash + if (workingCopyDiff.isBlank()) "" else "-dirty")
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should consider using the [gradle-git-properties](https://github.com/n0mer/gradle-git-properties) plugin instead. It contains all of the functionality you highlighted and it allows you to configure the results as **ext** properties or as an output file that can be rendered using the spring actuator *info* endpoint.

Comment: I've already found a nasty solution with buildSrc feature without a need to deal with kotlin gradle plugin problems. https://gist.github.com/gumyns/e9f0fc0004122af33a4ca758b0b51bf3